# Dynamodb schema design (map relational data to nosql)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to get my head around this example from AWS to map a relational model to nosql

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html

A key concept highlighted there is:

> **Important**
>
> .... Most well-designed applications require only one
>   table. ...

Given that, the example table is as follows

[image: dynamodb table]

It explains,

> You define the following entities, which support the relational order
>   entry schema:
>
> HR-Employee - PK: EmployeeID, SK: Employee Name
>
> HR-Region - PK: RegionID, SK: Region Name
>
> ...

However, the entity `HR-Employee - PK: EmployeeID, SK: Employee Name` in the example table has `SK` values which are not `Employee Name`s.

Also, it suggests the following query

[image]

but GSI-1 doesn't have PK of `Employee Name`.

I understand this could be a discrepancy in AWS documentation and I should raise it with them (which I have and they are notoriously bad in following up) but what I'm not sure is if the documentation is correct and my understanding is wrong (I'm inclined to believe the latter as AWS documentation is generally accurate).

Can someone guide me in the right direction in terms of a nosql schema mapping ? A correct example (with sample records of the dynamo table) for the schema in the above link would be much valued.

Answer (score 1):

So I'll try and make this clearer for you, let me know if something still doesn't make sense.

To start, you mention the fact that:

> However, the entity HR-Employee - PK: EmployeeID, SK: Employee Name in the example table has SK values which are not Employee Names.

The reason there are SK values that are not "Employee Names" is because the SK isn't only for "Employee Names", it is also used by other queries (such as Region Name, Country Name, etc.). Think of the SK as exactly what it stands for, a sort key. The documentation seems to miss the explanation of the extra SK they have, so let me summarize what you're looking at.

You have HR-Employee1, with Employee Name = Employee1, QuotaID (guessing what this key is) = QUOTA-2017-Q1, Some Other Key = HR-CONFIDENTIAL

These key names are not actually defined in the table, they all go under the sort key, and are only implicitly "employee name" or "quota id" or "region name".

What this allows you to do is query the employees data, using employeeID as PK and employee name as SK, but it also lets you query the employee Quota data (or whatever it is) by using employeeID as PK and quotaID as SK.

The same applies to your second question, concerning GSI-1. In essence, the way they have designed the table in this scenario is you have an SK "SortKey" where you can have various types of values to sort on, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But if the SK name is "SortKey" and values are employee name, region etc. then how do you handle conflicts? E.g. ID=123, Name and Region both are 'Austin'

Comment: In their case they specified conditions where those conflicts can't happen; for example they don't put region name SK under employee name PK, so if you ever search on a EmployeeID PK where SK = "Austin", the result can never hit a regionName SK since regionName is only existing under regionID PK.

Comment: But how can they know at design time that multiple SKs can have conflicts if they are not different types? If multiple rows contain different types isn't having conflicts a typical scenario? Even if SKs are IDs of different types (QuotaID and ProductID) they could also conflict can't they?

Comment: Personally, if they can conflict, then I would suggest putting them in separate tables. You pay for capacity usage, not per table, so having extra tables shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: When mixing data, it can be helpful to prefix the attribute value with its type. For example, `ID:123`, `FIRSTNAME:Austin`, `CITY:Austin`. That way, if you query for "Austin" you can prefix it with either `FIRSTNAME` or `CITY` so that you know you will get the right results.